# KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> - member fields question

Tags: .net

In looking at the source for the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` struct, the private member fields are only ever written to by the constructor.  Is there a design consideration of some sort as to why these are **not** marked `readonly`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not believe there was any explicit design decision here.  It was almost certainly an oversight by the original author of the code.

Also at the time of this types' authoring, the use of `readonly` was a bit controversial for this scenario.  A significant number of people felt it was bad practice to use `readonly` on a non-immutable field.  So much so that an FxCop rule was added to enforce this practice ([CA2104](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182302(VS.80).aspx)).  The type author could simply played by the rules of the time.

Comment: You saw it "was" controversial.  Has the controversy been settled?

Comment: @Jesse, it's still a bit controversial overall.  Luckily my last few groups have almost universally agreed that using `readonly` is correct so I tend to feel like it went away. But really I'm sure it's still a hot issue in a couple of places.

Comment: thanks.  I've been making **all** my fields `readonly` by default (much like starting my classes as `sealed` by default) and only carefully removing it if I find my design calls for mutability within the class.

Comment: @Jesse, this is the approach I favor as well.